# Why i am in getting undefined refrence error after linking liblas to Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, liblas

I am trying to link liblas library to Qt.I am using following code in .pro file to link it.

```
    //////////////code to link liblas to Qt/////////////////////////////////   
    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/lib/ -lliblas
    else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/lib/ -lliblas
    else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/lib/ -lliblas

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/include
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/include

    win32:CONFIG(release, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/lib/ -llaszip
    else:win32:CONFIG(debug, debug|release): LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/lib/ -llaszipd
    else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/lib/ -llaszip

    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/include
    DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/include
 ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
    and when i am running the code given below, I am getting undefined reference error
        ifstream stream;
        stream.open("lidar_sample.las", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        ReaderFactory f;
        Reader reader = f.CreateWithStream(stream);
    error: undefined reference to `liblas::ReaderFactory::CreateWithStream(std::istream&)'
```

Answer (score 0):

only two possible answers here.

1. your liblas is not found by the linker
2. your liblas is not
   the same version as your headers.

Comment: But I am getting all the liblas header files when i am including them in my .cpp

Comment: the header files are from this line:    INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/include , the library is from this line:     else:unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../../OSGeo4W/lib/ -lliblas   - verify that they are indeed correct.

Comment: Ok,understood.But how can i check for second possibility you have mentioned.

Comment: if you are on linux, run the nm tool on the library to see if it indeed has the method you are calling.

Comment: i am on windows

Comment: I have got lidar data and i want to extract x,y,z and intensity from that data.Is there some other simple way to do so.Please,if you could help.